# Magento 2 : How to Disable/Enable Custom Shipping Method Based on selected index of address

Tags: magento2

I want to show/hide custom shipping method like "My custom shipp" radio button if customer selects the first address.
If Customer insert/selects the second address on shipping page  "My custom shipp" will be disabled/hidden.

I have my custom module and there i have  the  code :

```
    public class MyShippp extends \Magento\Shipping\Model\Carrier\AbstractCarrier implements
        \Magento\Shipping\Model\Carrier\CarrierInterface
    {


//heres  the  constructor injection  etc


        /**
         * @param RateRequest $request
         * @return \Magento\Shipping\Model\Rate\Result|bool
         */
        public function collectRates(RateRequest $request)
        {


// here  i have to put some code  to
// verify which is the  index  of selected shipping  address.
// if  i select the  first address  i do something.
//else  i do something else;


            /** @var \Magento\Shipping\Model\Rate\Result $result */
            $result = $this->_rateResultFactory->create();
            $shippingPrice = $this->getConfigData('price');
            $method = $this->_rateMethodFactory->create();
            $method->setCarrier($this->_code);
            $method->setCarrierTitle($this->getConfigData('title'));
            $method->setMethod($this->_code);
            $method->setMethodTitle($this->getConfigData('name'));
            $method->setPrice(0);
            $method->setCost(0);
            $result->append($method);

            return $result;
        }




    }
```

How can i identify which is the index of selected address in this controller?

Comment: add what you have tried